# Does Android ARC enforce application permission the same way Android framework does it

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have written an Android application that does not require any permission. The fact that it does not require any permission is a proof to the user that it will not leak any sensitive information (typically through internet access).
I intend to run this application through ARC in the chrome browser on Windows/Linux.

Does ARC enforce application permissions? I have read that earlier version of ARC did not enforce anything here:
https://sslab.gtisc.gatech.edu/2014/arc-security.html

Thx for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Android permission is translated to [Chrome Apps permission](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions), because ARC is based on Chrome Apps.  But it's not a one-to-one mapping.

Even though you app has no permission, ARC Welder may add default permissions which are implicit on Android.  If you want to promise user for using no permission, you can modify the manifest.json in the zip file before uploading the the store.